# Counting in table with relationship issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I did an app to show a the last net_insurance but when i try to count in Insurance Financing

Here my tables

```
|policies|
 |id|  |num_policy|
  1       12345
  2       54654

|insurances|
 |id|  |id_policy| |net_insurance| 
  1       1          1000
  2       2          2000
  3       2          3000
  4       1          5000     

|insurance_financing|       
  |id| |id_ensurance| |number|
   1         2           9888
   2         2           1444
   3         4           2444
   4         4           1445


 |trying to obtain|
   |num_policy|   |last_net_insurance|  |count_InsuranceFinancing_by_IdEnsurance|
       12345         3000                          2
       54654         5000                          2
```

This is my controller

```
class PolicyController < ApplicationController
    def generate_print
      @policies= Policy.find(:all)
    end
end
```

This is my model

```
class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :insurances
end

class Insurance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :policy
  has_many :insurance_financing_details
end

class InsuranceFinancingDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :insurance
end
```

This is my view when i tried this

```
<% @policies.each do |p| %>

     <%= p.num_policy   %>
     <%  policy.insurances.last(1).each do |insurance| %>
        <% insurance.insurance_financing_details.each do |detail| %>
           <%= detail.number %>
        <% end %>
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I got this result

```
   |num_policy|   |last_net_insurance|  |count_InsuranceFinancing_by_IdEnsurance|
       12345         3000                          9888    1444
       54654         5000                          2444    1445
```

But i want

```
   |num_policy|   |last_net_insurance|  |count_InsuranceFinancing_by_IdEnsurance|
       12345         3000                          2
       54654         5000                          2
```

I tried this code and is not working

```
     <%  policy.insurances.last(1).each do |insurance| %>
        <% insurance.insurance_financing_details.size %>
     <% end %>
```

Tried this and is not working

```
     <%  policy.insurances.last(1).each do |insurance| %>
        <% insurance.insurance_financing_details.count %>
     <% end %>
```

And also tried but still not working

```
     <%  policy.insurances.last(1).insurance_financing_details.size %>
```

Please somebody can help me with this problem

I will really appreciate help

Comment: What exactly is the problem - are you getting a result you aren't expecting?  And what happens if you try this code from the console?  Also, note that the convention for a `belongs_to` relationship to use a foreign key column with the convention `belongs_to_model_id` (unless you specify otherwise) - so `id_policy` should be `policy_id` and `id_insurance` should be `insurance_id`.

Comment: I'm trying to count this      <%  policy.insurances.last(1).each do |insurance| %>
        <% insurance.insurance_financing_details.each do |detail| %>
           <%= detail.number %>
        <% end %>
     <% end %>

Comment: I added more details and edited it can you check again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `<%=` instead of `<%` when you want the result to be rendered:

```
<% insurance.insurance_financing_details.size %>
```

Should be:

```
<%= insurance.insurance_financing_details.size %>
```

Otherwise, it will render (in your case) the collection the block was iterating on.

Comment: Thank you sir :) sometimes a symbol can be difficult to understand 1 point and thanks

Comment: Pinnny i have another question using the same information? How can i ask it again? or need to re-post ?

Comment: @CarlitosMorales: If the question is unrelated to the previous question itself (even if  related to the data/code), you should ask another question - you can copy/paste your code if need be.  Otherwise, what's the question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668811/grouping-and-counting-information-in-table-relationship-issue

Comment: I will really appreciate your help